# I/O; reading values from text file and computing the data

Tags: c

So one of my assignment requires me to read from a text file with 3 columns and print out the sum and averages of each. I have gotten most of the code down but the sum of column one keeps printing out as 21.39000000. Can anyone give me an idea where I have gone wrong? Thanks!

I know I have the sums of the other two columns there but I'm ignoring it for now. Not sure how to upload my data but there are 10000 lines of numbers, in 3 columns.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    double n1=0, n2=0, n3=0;
    double sum1, sum2, sum3;
    double avg1,avg2,avg3;
    int count=0;
    FILE *inFile;

    inFile = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    if (inFile == NULL){
        printf("\nFailed to open file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        while(count<1001){
        fscanf(inFile,"%lf %lf %lf",&n1,&n2,&n3);
        sum1 += n1;
        sum2 += n2;
        sum3 += n3;
        count ++;
        avg1 = sum1/1000.00;
        }

    printf("\nSum is %lf\n", n1);
    printf("\nAverage is: %lf\n",avg1);
    }

fclose(inFile);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.You should init sum1 and sum2.
2.The line

```
avg1 = sum1/1000.00;
```

should be outside the while loop

3. The print should be

   printf("\nSum is %lf\n", sum1);
   Instead of

   printf("\nSum is %lf\n", n1);

Comment: Init means set it to 0.

Comment: Sum1=0;sum2=0;sum3=0;

Comment: Ah, okay that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should init `sum1`, `sum2` etc before add to them something.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably print `sum1`, and not `n1` wich is the last read value... and init the sum variables as stated elsewhere

Comment: Init all values with float/double 0.0, not an integer 0;